# Bypassing conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

Can anybody understand why the following code fails?

```
def main(A):
    A.sort()
    B = A[:]
    ll = len(B)
    while ll > 1:
        for i in range(ll):
            for n in range(i + 1, ll):
                 if (B[i] + B[n]) % 2 == 0:
                    B.remove(B[n])
                    B.remove(B[i])
                    main(B)
    return B
if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = main([4, 5, 3, 7, 2])
    print(result)
```

It runs ok until my list has only one value, reaches the "return B" statement, and then it jumps back into the loop again. What am I missing???

Comment: You are recursing , calling `main(B)` and ignoring the return value. Since you are making a *copy* of `A` each time, ignoring the return value *matters*.

Comment: I named several reasons as to why your code could 'fail' in my answer. For  a more detailed answer, including any *chance* at a working solution, please include in your question a proper [mcve]; the full traceback of the error and the *expected outcome*, i.e. what is the function *supposed to do*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using recursion, calling `main(B)` again in the loop. When the recursive call returns, the loop from which you called it *continues on*.

Moreover, you ignore the return value of the recursive calls. Since you use a *copy* of the list in each invocation of `main()`, ignoring the return value means you discard all the work the recursive call did.

Last but not least, you are deleting elements from `B`; you'll run into index errors with your loop as both `i` and `n` range to `ll`, a length that is no longer valid after removing elements. Since you can't update a `range()` object you are looping over; you'd have to use `while` loops that test the length each iteration:

```
i = 0
while i < len(B):
    n = i + 1
    while n < len(B):
        if (B[i] + B[n]) % 2 == 0:
            del B[n], B[i]
            break
        else:
            n += 1
    else:
        i += 1
```

The above loop will remove any two numbers from the list that sum up to an even number. Note that when you delete both the `n` and `i` values, you can  use the *index*, rather than search for the number with `list.remove()`.

The inner `while` loop uses an `else` suite; this is only executed when you *don't* break out of the loop, which only happens if we didn't just remove a value at index `i`. So when you *don't* find a pairing for `B[i]`, `i` is incremented to move on to the next candidate. If you *do* find a pairing`, the value at`i`is deleted, so now`B[i]` already references the next value.

I'm not sure why you'd need to recurse after this loop; a recursive call won't find more such pairings, since you test *every combination* already.

Demo, adding in copying by using `sorted()`:

```
>>> def main(A):
...     B = sorted(A)
...     i = 0
...     while i < len(B):
...         n = i + 1
...         while n < len(B):
...             if (B[i] + B[n]) % 2 == 0:
...                 del B[n], B[i]
...                 break
...             else:
...                 n += 1
...         else:
...             i += 1
...     return B
...
>>> main([4, 5, 3, 7, 2])
[7]
```

Comment: Very nice insight. Thank you Martijn Pieters. I have no index errors until the code "ignores" the return value and jumps into the loop again. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @VagelisProkopiou: that's only because you don't reach the index-error condition in the outer loop **yet**. It would get there too.